# Akka 2.5 and Slf4j throws NPE with nashorn

Tags: java, akka, slf4j, nashorn

I have a setup where i use Akka 2.5, and Slf4j (with loj4j2). But on startup it throws

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.lookup.MethodHandleFactory$StandardMethodHandleFunctionality.<init>(MethodHandleFactory.java:325)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.lookup.MethodHandleFactory.<clinit>(MethodHandleFactory.java:103)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.initLoggers(Context.java:1404)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:549)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:466)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$1.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:129)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$1.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:125)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:125)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:148)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:96)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:214)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.start(AsyncLoggerContext.java:76)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:34)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:89)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:551)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
 [java]     at com.lmax.disruptor.FatalExceptionHandler.<clinit>(FatalExceptionHandler.java:27)
 [java]     at com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.<init>(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:8)
 [java]     at com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.Disruptor.<init>(Disruptor.java:66)
 [java]     at com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.Disruptor.<init>(Disruptor.java:105)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerDisruptor.start(AsyncLoggerDisruptor.java:92)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.start(AsyncLoggerContext.java:75)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:307)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:215)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:74)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
 [java]     at com.aaa.aaa.AAAService.<clinit>(AAAService.java:45)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.initLoggers(Context.java:1404)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:549)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.<init>(Context.java:466)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$1.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:129)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$1.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:125)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:125)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:148)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:96)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:214)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.start(AsyncLoggerContext.java:76)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:34)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:89)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:551)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
 [java]     at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.logging.DebugLogger.instantiateLogger(DebugLogger.java:84)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.logging.DebugLogger.<init>(DebugLogger.java:77)
 [java]     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.logging.DebugLogger.<clinit>(DebugLogger.java:55)
 [java]     ... 43 more
 [java] 2017-05-24 11:07:18,278 main DEBUG Scala REPL Version: 2.0, Language: Scala, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {scala}
```

Any ideas, how to fix this ?

Comment: Are there any special class loaders involved or is this is a straight forward application using third-party libraries? And please do file a bug or send details to nashorn-dev openjdk alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Scala 2.12 with this. Then i changed it back to Scala 2.11. It fixed this issue.